# Deno on CentOS 7: 'GLIBC_2.18' not found

Tags: centos7, webfaction, deno

How to run [Deno](https://deno.land/) on [Webfaction](https://www.webfaction.com/)'s CentOS 7 (64-bit)?

It gives an error:

```
deno: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.18' not found (required by deno)
```

Comment: Did you find solution for installing `GLIBC_2.18` libraries on linux?

Comment: There are libraries here: https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/libc.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Current Deno release 1.0.0 (latest today) is not compatible with CentOS 7.

I tried on the latest distribution released on 27 April 2020:

```
$ cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS Linux release 7.8.2003 (Core)
```

This issue [7 GLIBC_2.18 not found](https://github.com/denoland/deno/issues/1658) suggests that there should be a way to solve this problem, but the thread seems to be abandoned for a year.

As of today Deno requires `GLIBC_2.18`, but unfortunately CentOS 7 is running `2.17`, an old version of the gclib which is not enough:

```
$ ldd --version
ldd (GNU libc) 2.17
```

If you need to run Deno on CentOS you'll need to use `CentOS 8`. Tested it and it works.

From [How to fix “/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found”](https://superuser.com/a/537694/251249):

> That means the program was compiled against glibc version 2.14, and it
>   requires that version to run, but your system has an older version
>   installed. You'll need to either recompile the program against the
>   version of glibc that's on your system, or install a newer version of
>   glibc (the "libc6" package in Debian).

It will not happen for CentOS 7. From [glibc_2.18 on Centos 7](https://forums.centos.org/viewtopic.php?t=71740):

> No. Never going to happen. We ship glibc 2.17 as part of CentOS 7 and
>   that will never change. It's part of the basic RHEL standards that
>   stuff like this does not change within a major version.

I wouldn't count on Deno — which is a new technology — to backport with old compilers. Consider upgrading your servers to CentOS 8.

Comment: `Consider upgrading your servers to CentOS 8.` :) I'm considering to upgrade but Webfaction still provides only CentOS 7 (August 2020).

Comment: @MiroslavPopov I've never used Webfaction, do they provide a VM for you or paas? Maybe reach out and ask for an exception, or preview if they are working on it. CentOS 8 was released almost a year ago... if they can't manage that then you should really consider another cloud provider.

Answer (score 1):

For me, I have no way to upgrade the OS as it's managed by IT department. Seems there's a workaround. I found the link on the following thread does work.

https://github.com/denoland/deno/issues/1658#issuecomment-632986792